# Get the key from a value in map Java

Tags: java, dictionary, key

Say I have a map such as:

```
{0='.', 1='.', 2='.', 3='.', 4='.', 5='.', 6='G'}
```

How do I find the key which matches the 'G' value?
Say I wanted to print the key for which 'G' is equal to.
All help appreciated

Comment: With a regular `Map`, you would have to iterate through all entries and return the key for the entry whose value matches yours.

Comment: What do you want for `.`?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  There's no 1-to-1 mapping from values to keys.  As @BheshGurung noted, what would you want to return if you looked for `'.'` instead of `'G'`?

Comment: @JimGarrison If looking for '.' would want it to return the first key which matches the value, in this case 0.

Comment: @pokeairguy: if you use common collection API then you will have to traverse the map and then find the key for value. But there is another API that is BidiMap<Key, Value> interface in the Collections library (provided by org.apache), is a bi-directional map, allowing you to map a key to a value (like normal maps), and also to map a value to a key, thus allowing you to perform lookups in both directions. Obtaining a key for a value is supported by the getKey() method. This Interface you can found in org.apache.commons.collections package.